# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _FlutterMethodNotImplemented

Tags: ios, xcode, dart, flutter

I am trying to run my flutter app on ios simulator which has few plugins such as connectivity, flutter_webview, fluttertoast etc.
When I am trying to run these I am getting following error on all of these plugins.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      -[FluttertoastPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in FluttertoastPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FluttertoastPlugin.o
```

Things are running smoothly on android.

I have tried

```
flutter clean 
pod install
```

Still the error persists.
Anyone facing similar error? If anyone has solution to this please help me with this. Thanks

flutter doctor -v output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.9, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 0.11.9 at /Users/vipin/Downloads/soft/flutter
    • Framework revision d48e6e433c (5 days ago), 2018-11-20 22:05:23 -0500
    • Engine revision 5c8147450d
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/vipin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/vipin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 30.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone XR • DAE7804F-C35A-4847-94AF-BC094BE584DC • ios • iOS 12.1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: is this error still happening? Maybe upgrading your Flutter version can solve this problem?

Answer (score 22):

If you're using app flavors and getting above error, have a look [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17749#issuecomment-615279343)

Comment: This is the easiest solution from that thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17749#issuecomment-615279343

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`
This worked for me - for the target that reports warnings, change the "Valid Architecture" setting to:

```
$(VALID_ARCHS)
x86_64
```

P.S In case this doesn't help, go to Build Settings and search for "No Common Blocks" and set it to "No". Build and Run.

Comment: valid architectures no longer exists apple changed it to Excluded architectures i have mine set to exclude arm64